# Show that Fourier transform is isomorphism between $H^r_m (\mathbb R)$ and $H^m_r (\mathbb R)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $H^m_r (\mathbb R) = \{u \in L^2(\mathbb R): \| \rho^r u \|_{H^m} < \infty \}$ and $H^r_m (\mathbb R) = \{u \in L^2(\mathbb R): \| \rho^m u \|_{H^r} < \infty \}$ where $\rho(x) = (1+|x|^2)^{\frac 1 2}$. It has been about a month that I have been showing that Fourier transform is an isomorphism between these two spaces, in every calculation I face the $\mathcal{F}(\rho^m u)$ which is complicated. I am assuming there is another way to show it other than normal calculations!Any comment or reference mentioning appreciated.

Comment: What notion of isomorphism do you use? Continuous linear bijection? What is the range of $r,m$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven It is not mentioned.

Comment: Did you mean $r,m$ are integers? As otherwise $H^r$ is defined in term of the Fourier transform. It is a Banach space isomorphism and even a Hilbert space isometry with the correct definition of the norms.

Comment: @reuns In the book he says $r,m \geq 0$. However, any case would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m,r \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$,

let $\mathbb{H}^r_m$  be the Hilbert space with norm $$\|f\|_{\mathbb{H}^m_r}^2 =\sum_{a\le m,b\le r}\|(2i\pi x)^a f^{(b)}\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R})}^2+\|((2i\pi x)^a f)^{(b)}\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R})}^2 $$

since $$\mathcal{F}( (2i\pi x)^m f^{(r)}) = ((-2i\pi y)^r\hat{f})^{(m)},\qquad\mathcal{F}( ((2i\pi x)^m f)^{(r)})= ((-2i\pi y)^r \hat{f}^{(m)}$$

we get that $\mathcal{F}$ is an isometry from $\mathbb{H}^m_r$ to $\mathbb{H}^r_m$.

It remains to check that your space $H^m_r$ is the same as $\mathbb{H}^m_r$.

When $m,r\in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ it is the same idea except that the $r$-th derivative is defined as $f^{(r)}=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((-2i\pi y)^r \hat{f})$.

Comment: I appreciate your enlightening. However, I have never seen this form of norm befor.